# Rails Schema changes unintentionally whenever I run rake db:migrate

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Whenever I run rake db:migrate, it updates my rails Schema by removing the foreign keys on one particular table. I can't understand why and I'm not sure how to prevent this from happening.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv8Ag.jpg

How can I solve this problem? I can't write another migration to re-add references because it throws a duplication error.

Comment: `schema.rb` is generated based on what's in your database, not what's in your migrations. That suggests that you don't have those three FKs in your database. Check the database directly (i.e. through the `mysql` CLI tool with no Rails in sight) and see if the FKs are really there.

Comment: Using the schema *with* the FKs, run `rails db:schema:load`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post the full migration file?

Also, have you tried rolling back to before the last migration using `rake db:rollback`? (You can also rollback several migrations, see [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#rolling-back))

CARE! Rolling back can delete data from your database so if you cannot afford to have that happen then perhaps this isn't the best solution.